# Thymeleaf behaving unexpectedly after viewResolver set to UTF-16

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, utf-16

I want to display my web page in different languages so, i changed my `thymeleaf` configuration to process `UTF-16` fonts but after doing that my entire web page style changes or I should say it's behaving unexpectedly. Below is my configuration file. Please help.

```java
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return templateResolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-16");
//        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your files actually stored and packed in `UTF-16`? Also do you really need `UTF-16` ar you using such weird encodings that it doesn't fit in `UTF-8`? Also instead of overhauling everything set the `spring.thymeleaf.encoding` property in `application.properties` to `UT-16`... That way you preserve the Spring Boot defaults. The same applies to `spring.thymeleaf.enableSpringElCompiler` you can set that to `true`.